# How to make Hibernate SessionFactory checkout JDBC connection from c3p0 upon session opening?

Tags: java, hibernate, connection, c3p0, sessionfactory

This would be useful because I want to know if the pool is exhausted BEFORE I need to create a Transaction from Session in my DAOs.

I would like to give feedback to the user about system overload (pool exhaustion), but I don't want to capture  this specific Exception in every method of every DAO. I think Session opening would be the right time to check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer versions of Hibernate have this Database connection property:

```
 hibernate.connection.acquisition_mode
```

which can be set to **IMMEDIATELY**, thus

> "The Connection will be acquired as soon as the Hibernate Session is
>   opened. This also circumvents ConnectionReleaseMode, as the Connection
>   will then be held until the Session is closed."

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate does it best to use a database connection as short as possible. Claiming a database connection when a session is opened goes against this (there are no queries available to perform, this will come later). A side effect would be that the pool is exhausted much sooner.

c3p0 uses a [checkoutTimeout](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#checkoutTimeout) to determine how long to wait for a connection to become available when the pool is exhausted. By default this timeout is 0 (i.e. no timeout) but if it is set to another value (e.g. 50 000 milliseconds) and the timeout is reached, a `SQLException` is thrown.

You can try to make an educated guess to see if the `checkoutTimeout` will be reached before you start a transaction, but it will always be a guess: it depends on how fast the other transactions complete. 

To make the guess you could use c3p0's [JMX interface](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#jmx_configuration_and_management) and get the values for the number of connections ([NumConnections](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/PooledDataSource.html#getNumConnectionsDefaultUser%28%29)), the number of busy connections ([NumBusyConnections](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/PooledDataSource.html#getNumBusyConnectionsDefaultUser%28%29)) and the number of threads waiting for a connection ([NumThreadsAwaitingCheckout](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/PooledDataSource.html#getNumThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser%28%29)).

If there are many busy connections and many threads are waiting, there is a good chance the `checkoutTimeout` will be reached, but you'll have to determine the exact numbers via stress-testing.